# How do I serialise a nested dictionary with Marshmallow?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I'm new to marshmallow and flask etc.
I'm trying to learn by creating an API that consumes a jsonified python dictionary. The dictionary contains nested dictionaries like this. It also contains a few Null items.

```
{
    "TITLE": "XXX",
    "NAME": "Mongoose",
    "TIME": "0430",
    "USED": null,
    "DESCRIPTION": "",
    "WEAPONS": {
        "HEAT": "Israel",
        "RADAR": "Flat",
        "CONV": {
            "S": true,
            "N": false,
            "A": false
         },
    },
}
```

I simply want to consume this back into a dictionary type. Something like this on the POST action

```
fields_schema = FieldSchema(many=True)
field_schema = FieldSchema()

json_data = request.get_json(force=True)
if not json_data:
    return {'message': 'No input data provided'}, 400
# Validate and deserialize input
try:
    data = field_schema.load(json_data)
except ValidationError as e:
    return e.messages, 422
```

Where data would simply be a nested dictionary.

It is defining the schema class that is causing me problems.
From what I can tell, when defining the schema, marshmallow doesnt have a JSON type and when I use fields.Dict I get the following error:

```
{
    "meta": [
        "Missing data for required field."
    ],
    "TITLE": [
        "Unknown field."
    etc...
```

I'm not sure whether I should be looking at using a nested Schema or whether I am totally over complicating things.

My fields_schema currently looks like this:

```
class FieldSchema(ma.Schema):
    id = fields.Integer()
    meta = fields.Dict(required=True)
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're going to validate the nested object, you can use Marshmallow's [`fields.Nested`](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/nesting.html) functionality.

Using their example

> ```
> from marshmallow import Schema, fields, pprint
>
> class UserSchema(Schema):
>     name = fields.String()
>     email = fields.Email()
>     created_at = fields.DateTime()
>
> class BlogSchema(Schema):
>     title = fields.String()
>     author = fields.Nested(UserSchema)
>
> user = User(name="Monty", email="monty@python.org")
> blog = Blog(title="Something Completely Different", author=user)
> result = BlogSchema().dump(blog)
> pprint(result)
> # {'title': u'Something Completely Different',
> #  'author': {'name': u'Monty',
> #             'email': u'monty@python.org',
> #             'created_at': '2014-08-17T14:58:57.600623+00:00'}}
> ```

Your need to define a schema from the root document though. Something like

```
class Widget(Schema):
    TITLE = fields.String()
    NAME = fields.String()
    # ...
    WEAPONS = fields.Nested(Weapon)

class Weapon(Schema):
    HEAT = fields.String()
    # ...
```

might get you going.

Comment: thank you. I will try going down this route. But another question... If i didnt want to validate the data as part of the serialisation would that change the solution?

Comment: If you didn't want to do any validation, you could stop at just `json_data = request.get_json(force=True)` of course. If you didn't want to validate the inside of `WEAPONS` but you did want to validate the rest you could define it as a `fields.Dict()` (instead of a nested schema).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that has made things a lot clearer to me.

Comment: @AndrewF, any suggestions on how using `flask_marshmallow` we could serialize the `db.Column(JSONB)` columns of postgress [such as here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67409500/6484358)